# UDID is not displayed on Testflight after updating Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, testflight

I have added UDIDs on my developer portal and made a new provisioning profile by adding those UDIDs.

But when I upload that profile to Testflight, those UDIDs are not displayed.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testflight ownership remains to only one account at a time.

If we are not able to find the UDID in the device list, go to Activity tab. You will get the UDID with the registered person's name over there.

Thanks :)